# Установка единого значения свойства объектам на форме WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

1. На форме WPF есть несколько `TextBlock`. Как программно по нажатию кнопки установить у них всех к примеру свойство `Visible` в `false`?

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос - биндинги. Биндите у всех свойство Visibility на одной свойство модели и меняете его програмно, когда надо.

Comment: DependencyProperty?

Comment: В чем вопрос то? Да, Visibility это DependencyProperty.

Comment: уточняю... пробую

Comment: надо создать свойство, которое меняется по нажанию кнопки. и надо TextBlock'и с помощью DataBinding привязать их Visibility к этому свойству.

Comment: а искать элементы можно с помощью VisualTreeHelper.GetChild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь MVVM (а чем ещё?), у вас не должно быть желания обработать *все* текстбоксы на странице — вы должны думать не в терминах контролов, а в терминах показываемых на странице сущностей. Тем более что визуальное представление любого из объектов может поменяться, `TextBox` может поменяться на другой контрол, а вам скорее всего хочется отключить видимость этого элемента, какого бы типа он ни был.

Поэтому правильное решение — выставить в VM свойство наподобие IsVisible, и привязываться к нему. По команде из UI переключать на уровне бизнес-логики свойства IsVisible у нужных VM-объектов, и дать UI автоматически подхватить эти изменения.

---

Альтернативное, более техническое решение наподобие изложенного в соседнем ответе: binding к свойству + общий стиль. (Я бы всё же советовал управлять на уровне VM.)

Пример:

```
<Window x:Class="DisableAll.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="root">
    <Window.Tag><sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean></Window.Tag>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBox/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root}">Edit mode</CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

Если нужно для некоторых TextBox'ов включать, а для других выключать видимость по «общему» сигналу, придётся создать свой конвертер. Это совсем не сложно:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityInvertedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return object.Equals(value, Visibility.Collapsed);
    }
}
```

Ну и теперь можно подключить к коду. Один из многих способов:

```
<Window x:Class="DisableAll.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DisableAll"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="root">
    <Window.Tag><sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean></Window.Tag>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityInvertedConverter x:Key="B2NV"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox
            Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
        <TextBox
            Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
        <TextBox
            Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource B2NV}}"/>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root}">Edit mode</ToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Или можно уложить это в два стиля, чтобы код был проще.

Comment: Спасибо, прикольно

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: Пожалуйста!

Comment: А подскажи, как привязать, если не `Checkbox`, а кнопка?

Comment: А если не использовать Tag. Создать свое свойство через DependencyProperty?

Comment: И как присвоить значение обратное Tag

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: С кнопкой тоже несложно: `<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root}">Edit mode</ToggleButton>`

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: Если не использовать `Tag`, то да, нужно кастомное dependency property.

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: Не совсем понял, что такое «обратное значение». Если вы хотите поменять значение `Tag` в code-behind, надо как-то так: `Tag = !(bool)Tag;`

Comment: Я имел в виду: `IsChecked="{Binding !(Tag), ElementName=root}"` что-то типа этого. Т.е. одни становятся видимыми, а другие нет.

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: А, понял. Смотрите обновление ответа.

Answer (score 2):

1. Установка одинакового значения определенного свойства для нескольких элементов:

   К примеру, нам нужно скрыть несколько элементов по нажатию кнопки.
   Добавляем свойство:

   ```
   private static readonly DependencyProperty EditModeProperty=
   DependencyProperty.Register("EditMode", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MainWindow));

   public Visibility EditMode
   {
       get { return (Visibility)this.GetValue(EditModeProperty); }
       set {this.SetValue(EditModeProperty, value);}
   }
   ```

По нажатию кнопки прописываем следующее:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  EditMode = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Переходим к XAML:

```
<TextBox Height="23"Text="TextBox" Width="120" 
Visibility="{Binding EditMode, ElementName=window}"/>
```

Comment: вот дурной редактор...

Comment: согласен с редактором

Comment: Хм, вот теперь я понял, почему вы уточняли о свойстве зависимостей. На самом деле, в WPF принято использовать отдельный класс в качестве контекста для отображения, который забивают так или иначе в DataContext всего окна или конкретных его элементов. В MVVM такой класс обзывается вью_моделью и он уже как раз содержит обычное свойство типа `Visibility`, с поддержкой интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`