# Управление visibility одного элемента через нажатие на другой

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Нужно по нажатию кнопки отобразить другой элемент находищийся в состоянии `collapse`.
Использую `binding` к булевой переменной во `ViewModel` и конвертер, но вдруг задумался, что это лишняя сущность, и наверняка можно через xaml и триггеры, но никак не могу нарыть примеры. Подскажите.

P.S. Поясняю, интересует реализация чисто через xaml без дерганья конвертеров и кода `ViewModel`. Возможно ли справится чисто силами `View`?

Comment: `Button` или `ToggleButton`?

Comment: Дмитрий, 'Button'

Comment: Тогда кроме модели больше ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: А что `ToggleButton` поменяет? Что-то не уловлю =)

Comment: У [`ToggleButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton(v=vs.110).aspx) есть сотояние [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) которое можно использовать в `Binding`

Comment: `IsChecked`  принимает значение `True`, либо `False`. Это не подходит для `Visibility`.

Comment: Да, опять конвертор использовать.

Comment: Посмотрите аналогичную тему. [Установка единого значения свойства объектам на форме WPF](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484766/)

Comment: Если не хотите использовать конвертер, то используйте триггеры

Comment: Ну да, можно и так) Но разница небольшая) Я там уточнил вопрос, чего хочу добиться.

Answer (score 1):

Есть уже готовый конвертер: [MSDN: BooleanToVisibilityConverter - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Вот пример использования:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="root">

<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisConverter"/>
</Window.Resources> 

<Window.Tag>
    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
</Window.Tag>

<Grid >
    <Button Content="Show/Hile" Margin="26,34,384,238" Click="Button_Click"/>

    <Label Content="Test text" Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource VisConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Да не, я с конвертером так и делаю. Просто задался вопросом можно ли делать чисто через `xaml` не дергая код Вьюмодели или конвертеров.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без конвертера. Используем Trigger.

```
    <ToggleButton Content="Click Me" x:Name="toggleMe" Width="150" Height="24"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Test textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=toggleMe}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Всё хорошо и такой способ я знаю, но нужно силами `view` только через `xaml` - если такое вообще возможно, конечно.

Comment: С использованием `ToggleButton` не подходит вариант? Подправил ответ.

Comment: Подходит. Но я ищу более универсальный вариант. Если он возможен, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием тригера и анимации.

```
<Button Content="Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference testTextBox}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock Text="Test textbox" x:Name="testTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```